# Scale text size to fill button

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a button on my bootstrap website.

```
<input type="submit" value="GET INSTANT ACCESS!"class="btn btn-lg">
```

I have used css to make its width 100%.

```
.btn-lg {
        width: 100%;
    }
```

I would like to scale the text inside the button to fill the width of the button (which fills the width of its containing div). However, I do not want the text to cause the button width to be greater than 100% and stretch the div that it is contained in.

What I would like is the text being scaled to the width of the button:
[image: what I would like]
rather than the text being to small
[image: what I would not like]
or the text being too large and causing the webpage width to be greater than the device width
[image: what I would not like]

Comment: You can't scale text proportional to element size with CSS. You would need javascript.

Comment: Im with Paulie_D here, you have a button which is 100% width, ok I'm with you on that, but you want to stretch the text across the whole button? Do you mean if the button has a height of 50px the text should be as height as the button ?

Comment: @Paulie_D I have added images to show what I mean

Comment: @Canvas I have added images to show what I mean

Comment: As I said, you can't scale text proportional to element width with CSS so the images really don't help. We know what you want and are telling you...you need JS. - http://fittextjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

If JS(jQuery) is an acceptable solution, please see [my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kiirosora/fjczy6jq/).

You can use `fitText(elem)` function on events where you need to adjust the font size to fit.

```js
$('.container').each(function() {
    fitText($(this).find(':submit').get(0));
});

function fitText(elem) {
    var $button = $(elem),
        size = 1; // your preferred initial size
    console.log($button.attr('type'));
    for (;size < 150; size++ ) {
        $button.css('font-size', size + 'px');
        var currentLH = parseInt($button.css('font-size'), 10);
        if (parseInt($button.height(), 10) >= (currentLH * 2)) {
            size--;
            $button.css('font-size', size + 'px');
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.container {
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 0 0 10px;
}
.c1 { width: 150px; }
.c2 { width: 400px; }
.c3 { width: 100%; }
.btn-lg {
    width: 100%;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container c1">
    <input type="submit" value="GET INSTANT ACCESS!" class="btn btn-lg" />
</div>
<div class="container c2">
    <input type="submit" value="GET INSTANT ACCESS!" class="btn btn-lg" />
</div>
<div class="container c3">
    <input type="submit" value="GET INSTANT ACCESS!" class="btn btn-lg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want your button's width to be greater than 100%, you have to add it in your css :
`.btn-lg {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}`

That will not allow your button to be larger to 100%.

Comment: This does not answer the question which relates to text size not the button size.